# Segfaults on initialization of array of pthread_t

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, pthreads, variable-length-array

I have a program that takes input `n` from the command line, and, as part of its operation, tries to call the following code:

```
pthread_t threads[n*n];
```

Now, for any `n <= 1023`, this works fine, but the moment I try to use `n > 1023`, I get a segfault. It is this particular line that causes it - my code does not advance beyond it. I'm a little confused as to why this is happening, and would appreciate all possible help.

Comment: One megathread?  Good luck with that.

Comment: Yeah, I realize *now* that this wasn't such a brilliant idea. Still helps to know what my stack allocation limits are, I guess...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the size of the array (i.e. the size of the pointer times 2^20) is too large to be held in the automatic memory (i.e. on the stack). You can fix this by using dynamic allocation:

```
pthread_t *threads = malloc(sizeof(pthread_t) * n * n);
```

Of course you need to free this memory once you are done with the array:

```
free(threads);
```